# How do I show the path of Bfs?

Tags: c#, graph, breadth-first-search

So I'm trying to make BFS algorithm, and I was able to calculate the shortest path distance between each 2 nodes. But the neighbors of each node (i.e node A) is not only nodes it's a dictionary of nodes as a key and a hashset of matches where each two nodes played in. Now, I don't know how to store the path while the BFS is working... This the adjacency function that returns the neighbors of each nodes

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> dic= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary < string,, HashSet < string >>>;

  public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>> adjacentto(string v)
    {
        return dic[v];
    }
```

And this is my BFS function:

```
    private Dictionary<string, int> dist = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public void BFSDegree(Graph g, string s, string p)
    {
        Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

        dist.Add(s, 0);
        q.Enqueue(s);

        while (q.Count() != 0)
        {
            string j = q.Dequeue();
            //count = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>> h in g.adjacentto(j))
            {
                    if (!dist.ContainsKey(h.Key))
                    {
                        q.Enqueue(h.Key);
                        dist.Add(h.Key, 1 + dist[j]);


                    }

                    if (j == p)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("             " + dist[j]);                            
                        return;

                    }
                }


            }


        }
```

So, what I need it is to go see the path and read the values of the hashset, for example node A and node B played together in 3 matches match 1, match 2, match 7 so this should be the path. So I'm gonna print to the console "The path is either match 1, match 2 or match 7). And the same thing if I had 2 nodes that didn't star in a match together but they both starred with node A in 2 separate matches so the path should be through either of these 2 matches. How do I keep track of the paths and store the path while operating BFS? This is the file I'm reading the graph from.

[image]

This is the how I built my graph
 [image]

And this is what I want to achieve
[image]

I was able to achieve the first goal (degree) through using BFS. But now I don't know how to achieve the "chain" or the path. The chain is nothing but the number of the movies in the path so I think if I'm able to save the path (show the path) while the BFS is working I shall be able to achieve the chain. So my problem is the last goal how do I save the path and show it.

Comment: You question is hard to understand. Can you specify with an example what you mean ? Maybe give an example of what your graph will look like and the result ?

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully you can understand my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the shortest path from one node to another, you can keep track of parents of each node. for example the graph below, when I run bfs from 0 up to 9, I keep track of each node reached an assign a parent. Once a parent is assigned, I do not reassign. So for example, if I want to find path from 0 to 9 and length I simply backtrack i.e. 9-7-3-1-0 so start from 9's parent and check 7's parent and so forth until you get to start node. We can easily then get the length.

[image: Bfs path]

As for the query, when you do something like C/E you can first run bfs to check for the path "which should be 2 going from C-A-E" and of course there could be other paths but I guess shortest path is the best for what you want ?
Anyway, let's assume we choose path C-A-E we can update the Rel. by the number of edges so Rel = 2 and then Chain will be

```
//Nodes -> [C, A, E] 
//Parents ->[C, C, A]
Start from E // which is destination
Get movies of parent // parent is A, returns Movies 2
move to parent // now we are checking A
Get movies of parent // parent is C, returns Movies 1 Movies 7
break;
```

You break as soon as you reach source or you can do it vice versa
At the end you have Movies 2,1, and 7

A parent is just a predecessor of a node. For example, while you run Bfs if you go from 0 to 1 then 0 is parent of 1

Here is an implementation that I hope will help you understand it a little better.

```
private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> _adjacencyList;
private Map<Integer, String> _movies; // will store neighbors here
private Queue<Integer> queue;
private int [] visited;

public BaconNumber(int V){// v here is number of vertices
    _adjacencyList = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    _movies = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    visited = new int[V];
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++){
        _adjacencyList.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());// add a linkedlist             for each vertex
        visited[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

Fill movies here

```
private void fillNeighbors(){
    //0 = A, 1 = B, 2 = C, 3 = D, 4 = E
    _movies.put(0, "Z Movie 0 | B Movie 1 Movie 2 Movie 7 | C Movie 1 Movie 7 | D Movie 2 Movie 7 | E Movie 2");
    _movies.put(1, "A Movie 1 Movie 2 Movie 7 | C Movie 1 Movie 7 | D Movie 2 Movie 7 | E Movie 2");
    _movies.put(2, "A Movie 1 Movie 7 | B Movie 1 Movie 7 | D Movie 7");
    _movies.put(3, "E Movie 2 | A Movie 2 Movie 7 | B Movie 2 Movie 7 | C Movie 7");
    _movies.put(4, "D Movie 2 | A Movie 2 | B Movie 2 | F Movie 3 | G Movie 3");
}
```

Get movies. This takes in two parameters. One for where we get the movie from and the other for the node we are looking for. Note that I converted the second parameter to a letter so it looks like what you have

```
public String getMovies(int s, int v){
    String result = "";
    // just getting corresponding character
    int rem = v % 26;
    char l = (char)((int)'A' + rem);
    //System.out.println("this is char "+l);
    String movie = _movies.get(s);
    String [] tokens = movie.split("\\|");
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
        String next = tokens[i];
        if(next.contains(String.valueOf(l))){
            result = next;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And now the query part

```
String query(int source, int dest){
    List<Integer> nodes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int i, element;
    visited[source] = source;
    queue.add(source);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        element = queue.remove();
        i = element;
        if(i == dest) break; // we stop as soon as we reach destination
        nodes.add(element);
        List<Integer> iList = getEdge(i);
        System.out.println(i+" -> "+iList);
        int x = 0; 
        while(x < iList.size()){
            int index = iList.get(x);
            if(visited[index] == -1){
                queue.add(index);
                visited[index] = i;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
    String result = "";
    for(int x = dest; x >= 0; x= visited[x]){
        if(x == source) break; // we are done
        if(visited[x] != -1){
            result += getMovies(x,visited[x]); // get predecessor of x movies from x
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, it's really helpful. I'm not that familiar with the concept of backtracking though, am I supposed to make a declare a data structure that stores the path while the BFS is operating? And what do you mean by parents on my code?

Comment: Result of the above should look something like this 
 A Movie 2  C Movie 1 Movie 7

Comment: I definitely understand you better now! Thank you so much, now I will try and apply this on my code, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.